# Error when upgrading the package

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python, dpkg

I want to do an upgrade so I did: `sudo apt-get update`
and then: `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Returns an error:

```
The list of "python-dev" package files contains an empty file name
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The empty file name error and other ensuing multiple package management errors may have been the result of using a damaged SD card. If errors like these reoccur you should consider using a different SD card.

Reinstall the package that contains an empty file name (python-dev). Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-dev.list   
sudo dpkg --configure -a   
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dev # first 3 commands fixed the python-dev error
sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1*  
sudo apt-get autoclean  
sudo apt-get update   
sudo dpkg -P mc mc-data # remove Midnight Commander
```

In order to get Midnight Commander working again after you have solved the package management issues you need to reinstall Midnight Commander.

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Comment: `E: dpkg has been interrupted, you must do it manually sudo dpkg --configure -a to fix the problem.`

I did `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

And then I did `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dev`

And the same goes for it `dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, interruption:
  the package file list "python-dev" contains an empty file name
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (2)`

Comment: `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-dev.list`
and
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dev` it helped, but now I have
`dpkg: archive processing error /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.2-3+deb8u4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
  attempt to overwrite "/ usr / share / man / ru / man1", which also exists in the mc-data 3 package: 4.8.13-3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess has been killed with a signal (interrupted pipe)
Processing of man-db package triggers (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors occurred while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.2-3+deb8u4_armhf.deb`

Comment: the same error
`dpkg: archive processing error /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.2-3+deb8u4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
  attempt to overwrite "/ usr / share / man / ru / man1", which also exists in the mc-data 3 package: 4.8.13-3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess has been killed with a signal (interrupted pipe)
Processing of man-db package triggers (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors occurred while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.2-3+deb8u4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: sudo dpkg -P mc-data returns `dpkg: dependency problems prevent the removal of mc-data:
  mc depends on mc-data (= 3: 4.8.13-3).dpkg: mc-data package processing error (--purge):
  dependency problems - will not be removed
Errors occurred while processing:
  mc-date`

Comment: I'll put on another SD card. If this does not help, unfortunately I will be forced to put the system back again, because there are still problems with it. Either way, thank you for your help.

Comment: What OS are you using, Raspbian? Next time you have a question about Raspbian ask it at [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)